# Windows 7 Gadgets no longer always-on-desktop

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

On my machine, the gadgets suddenly stopped staying on desktop if I press *show desktop* like other applications.
They are visible when I use the "peek desktop" feature, the win+g combo works and they are present over there in general.

I tried disabling and re-enabling them and the proper occured on my Win7 64-bit and 32-bit installations.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: This happens in my laptop too when you do a Win+D. Fixed by a simple Refresh of the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a system restore from before they started disappearing? Not sure if they would roll back as well, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I'm unaware of the day unfortunately, the last restore points are all system updates for me..